# I've been getting this error running this code

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class SimpleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.TextField()
    is_alive = serializers.BooleanField()
    amount = serializers.FloatField()
    extra_name = serializers.CharField()
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

I've been getting this error
description=serializers.TextField()AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'TextField'

Answer (score 2):

There is no `TextField`, it's not a direct mapping 1:1 with `django.db.models.*Field`, just use `serializers.CharField()` instead.

See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#string-fields for the fields available.